# Entry type for … isn't style-file defined

Tags: multiple-citations

I'm using overleaf and I have this warning:

```
entry type for "hadoop" isn't style-file defined


entry type for "spark" isn't style-file defined
```

Here is the citations for them:

```
@software{hadoop,
  author = {{Apache Software Foundation}},
  title = {Hadoop},
  url = {https://hadoop.apache.org},
  version = {0.20.2},
  date = {2010-02-19},
}

@software{spark,
 title={Apache spark™ - unified engine for large-scale data analytics},
 url={http://spark.incubator.apache.org/},
}
```

I'm not sure if I have defined them well or not?

Comment: you have entries `@software` but using a bib style that does not have a `software` document type, you could use a different style or use `@misc` or ignore the warning

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What about the citations of Hadoop and Spark? Is it correct? Because I couldn't find a way to cite them.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sorry I mean the rest of citations

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have the code above. I don't have any problem with compiling. I just ask about the way to cite Hadoop and Spark is it correct?

Comment: David already answered your question. The bibliogaphy style you're using does not support `@software` entries in bib files. Probably you should switch them to `@misc` entries, and possibly change some of the field names, and then you could cite them. We'd give more details, but we don't know what style you're using, or what actual code for the citations.